# Get a file from a public ASP.NET Core API which consumes DMZ API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two APIs: DMZ and Public (public consumes dmz)
1. DMZ:

```
    public FileStreamResult GetContent(int id)
    {
        var content = from m in db.messagestoimages
                      where m.Message == id
                      select m;

        if (content == null || content.Count() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string fileName = content.First().ImageURL;

        string fullPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  + fileName;
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            var result = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "image/jpeg");
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

2: Public API

```
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public FileStreamResult Get(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string host = configuration.GetSection("MySettings").GetSection("OctopusURL").Value;

                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(host);

                        var response = client.GetAsync("api/Content/" + id);
                        var stream = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg")
                        {
                            FileDownloadName = "test.jpeg"
                        };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null; // 500 is generic server error
        }
    }
```

My problem is when i get File from public API, it is wrong, i can not open the file, windows says format is not supported. Size of the file that i get is smaller than original which probably means that file was transferred partially or with error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning the `FileStream` to HTTP response directly may cause the client to download the file incompletely.

This is because the stream between the server and the client is not stable. The transfer may pause, may be impacted, may cancel. But the reading process from server and disk requires a stable connection and stable speed.

You can use a `MemoryStream` to copy and return a file to the HTTP response stream. But `MemoryStream` uses lots of memory which may cause the entire server to stop working.

`BufferedStream` to return file is a better way. Fast, stable and causes less.

But the best way to return a local file from server in .NET Core is to use:

```cs
Controller.PhysicalFileResult PhysicalFile(string physicalPath, string contentType, bool enableRangeProcessing);
```

Modify your DMZ API to use `PhysicalFile` to return a file to get the best performance and stability. Like this:

```cs
    public IActionResult GetContent(int id)
    {
        var content = from m in db.messagestoimages
                      where m.Message == id
                      select m;

        if (content == null || content.Count() == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        string fileName = content.First().ImageURL;

        string fullPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  + fileName;
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            return PhysicalFile(fullPath, "image/jpeg", true);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

And for your public API, I have tested with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Temp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
                var response = client.GetAsync("/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
                var stream = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(mstream);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("a.png", mstream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine and successfully downloaded the file which also can be opened successfully.

I guess it was not the problem for you public API.

Comment: Thanks for such an extended response. Problem is that DMZ API is written in MVC, not asp.net Core. Public API is on Core. Public API is consumed by end clients.

Comment: If you can't access the `PhysicalFile` function, please consider using a buffered stream to send the file stream to the client.